# System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework-core, setup

Из Visual Studio проект запускается, работает без проблем
На том же ПК делаю setup wizard project, выбираю файлы для публикации.
Устанавливаю на этот же ПК
Программа даже не открывается, в Event Viewer такая ошибка: `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.`

Добавление `<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` в файл проекта не помогло, после этого программа просто не запускается, даже без ошибки в Event Viewer. Пробовал установить `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI`- не работает ( жалуется на `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer` в коде, который я не смог заменить ).

winforms, .net 6.0,

nuget:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0,
entityframeworkcore 6.0.7,
entityframeworkcore.SqlServer 6.0.7,
entityframeworkcore.Tools 6.0.7

codefirst метод

Comment: У меня был длительный, примерно в неделю, период борьбы с некой другой ошибкой, которая появляется при использовании Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. Я победил! Можно глянуть вот этот вопрос, может, у Вас что то похожее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437427/

Comment: @S.H. publish работает отлично, но. к сожалению, с setup wizard совсем иначе (

Comment: А на какой версии винды Вы пытаетесь запустить ппроект? Вообще, я это вот к чему: я как то прикручивал EF к старому проекту на winforms, и там - да, пришлось поплясать с бубном. но примерно за день даже такой не сильно продвинутый в хождении по граблям прошел этот лабиринт. Может, Вам попробовать сделать минимальный воспроизводимый пример, и добавить его в вопрос? вдруг кто то сможет помочь?